# Can I someone help me to debug the tf.PaddingFIFOQueue error?

Tags: tensorflow, shapes

Since I am new to tensorflow, I have not idea how to define the shapes for tf.PaddingFIFOQueue to set the element as an N*1 array. I thought the following code should work, but it produced errors ...

Could you please give me a hint to debug this?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.placeholder(dtype= tf.float32, shape = [None, 1])
b = tf.placeholder(dtype= tf.float32, shape = [None, 1])

ab_value = np.random.randn(5,1)
m = ab_value.reshape(-1, 1)

q_ab = tf.PaddingFIFOQueue(32, ['float32', 'float32'], shapes = [[None, 1], [None, 1]])
q_ab_en = q_ab.enqueue_many([a, b])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(q_ab_en, feed_dict = {a: ab_value, b: ab_value})

#a_dq, b_dq = q_ab.dequeue_many(1)
```

> File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py",
>   line 375, in enqueue_many
>   val.get_shape()[1:].assert_is_compatible_with(shape)
>   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py",
>   line 756, in assert_is_compatible_with raise ValueError("Shapes %s and
>   %s are incompatible" % (self, other)) 
>   ValueError: Shapes (1,) and (?,1) are incompatible

Answer (score 0):

Are a and b single elements or many elements?

enqueue_many is equivalent to batched enqueue calls. so if you have a.shape = [5, 1] calling enqueue_many(a) is equivalent to calling enqueue(a[0]), enqueue(a[1]), ..., enqueue(a[-1]).

If that is the intended behavior you should change the shape of your queue to:
q_ab = tf.PaddingFIFOQueue(32, ['float32', 'float32'], shapes = [[1], [1]])

If a and b represent a single sample than you should use enqueue instead of enqueue_many.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Very helpful to me! I just fixed the problem by using enqueue instead of enqueue_many.